# iis express always reports port in use

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express-10

Visual Studio Community 2019 16.10.0

[image]

Pressing [IIS Express] to debug...

Regardless of which Port I use, I get:

[image]

Log:

Failed to register URL "http://localhost:59001/" for site "...." application "/". Error description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (0x80070020)

Rebooted, deleted 'vs' folder, reinstalled VS 2019.  Still the same error.  Does anyone know what could be causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing the "Repair" option on Visual Studio fixed it.  But uninstall/reinstall did not?!?